# js function that works exactly as excel's number dividing by thousands

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you may know in excel when some cell is in focus and you write for example `1500.32` it shows `1500.32`, however when you click enter or blur that cell it shows `1 500.32`. I am curious how can I do it. For now I have created directive, but cannot think how to perform  the rest of that. Thanks

Comment: So u want to do this in JavaScript?
If yes, please provide sample code that you have tried to get help!

Answer (score 1):

This code would separate the thousands... :p

```js
function expand (numValue) {
 while ( numValue.match(/^[0-9]{4}/) ) {
   numValue = numValue.replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{3}(\.|$| ))/,"$1 $2");
  }
 return numValue;
}

function collapse (numValue) {
 return numValue.replace(/ /g,"");
}

$(".myNumber").click(function(){
 $(this).val( expand($(this).val()) );
})

$(".myNumber").blur(function(){
 $(this).val( collapse($(this).val()) );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="myNumber" value="12345126789.12">

<input class="myNumber" value="78913.12">
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format):

```
var options = { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' };
var numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', options);
console.log(numberFormat.format(654321.987));
```

returns:

> £654,321.99

and swap the comma for a space with regular expressions.

Using language code `fr-FR` gives a space, but you still have to edit other details.